# Strange Return Value

Tags: c++, winapi

My code,

```
LPSTR Internal::Gz_GetSystemKey( BOOL SHOW_ERROR, BOOL SHOW_KEY ) {

    HW_PROFILE_INFO   HwProfInfo;
    if (!GetCurrentHwProfile(&HwProfInfo)) 
    {
        if(SHOW_ERROR)
            Message::Error( "An Internal Error Has Occurred", "Gizmo Message", TRUE );
        return NULL;
    }

    std::string __clean( (char*)HwProfInfo.szHwProfileGuid );
    __clean.append( std::string( (char*)HwProfInfo.szHwProfileName ) );

    LPSTR neet_key = Crypt::CRC32( Crypt::MD5( (char*)__clean.c_str() ) );

    if (SHOW_KEY)
        Message::Info( neet_key ); // shows expected result

    return neet_key; // returns strange ascii result
};

Gz BOOL Gz_CreateContext( BOOL SHOW_ERROR, BOOL SHOW_KEY ) {

    HKEY CHECK; // key result container
    BOOL RESULT;
    std::wstring neet_key_uni; // must use unicode string in RegSetValueExW

    if ( RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\NEET\\Gizmo\\"), &CHECK) != ERROR_SUCCESS )
        goto CREATE_REG_CONTEXT;
    else
        goto STORE_NEET_KEY;

CREATE_REG_CONTEXT:

    if ( RegCreateKeyA( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\NEET\\Gizmo\\", &CHECK ) != ERROR_SUCCESS ) {

        if( SHOW_ERROR )
            Message::Error( "Context Could Not Be Created" );
         RESULT = FALSE;
         goto END_MACRO;
    }

STORE_NEET_KEY:

    LPSTR neet_key = Internal::Gz_GetSystemKey( SHOW_ERROR, SHOW_KEY ); // GetSystemKey generates good key, returns weird ascii
    Message::Notify( neet_key );
    neet_key_uni = std::wstring(neet_key, neet_key+strlen(neet_key));

    if ( RegSetValueEx( CHECK, TEXT("Key"), 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)neet_key_uni.c_str(), ( neet_key_uni.size() + 1 ) * sizeof( wchar_t ) ) != ERROR_SUCCESS ) {

        if( SHOW_ERROR )
            Message::Error( "Context Could Not Be Reached" );
        RESULT = FALSE;
        goto END_MACRO;
    }

    RESULT = TRUE;

END_MACRO:

    RegCloseKey(CHECK); // safely close registry key
    return RESULT;
};
```

I'm creating a simple PC identification lib for practice, not for commercial use.

```
Message::Info( neet_key );
```

Shows

[image]

but the actual return value is

[image: http://gyazo.com/82b25d02e123b56da217c7ff5cb01e57]

Any ideas why? The 'Message' namespace/functions are just message boxes. As for the 'Crypt' namespace/functions, they aren't the issue at hand.

Comment: Who owns the memory for the 'neet_key'? My guess would be that the 'Message::Info' shows a valid value because whatever memory structure its from is still in memory but when you return its no longer in memory. Therefore the returned value prints rubbish.

Comment: That's a rather gratuitous use of gotos.

Comment: @ooga ... but you repeat yourself...

Comment: @DrewDormann I get it! Because *all* uses of goto are gratuitous. :-) (Nice one.)

Comment: I got curious so I traced 'neet_key',
http://gyazo.com/93eba805d100d898568370144f592672

then becomes,
http://gyazo.com/76f00dfa330330b7ddffd565c920ead4

After execution.

Comment: @Veritas what did you discover?

Comment: I beleive @karmasponge was correct.

Comment: @karmasponge you could post your comment as an answer...

Comment: As an aside, identifiers which begin with double underscores (i.e., `__clean`) are reserved for the implementation and using them results in undefined behavior.

Comment: There are literally tens of problems with this code. You cannot continue like this. Stop casting. Stop using C strings. Stop using goto. Learn about const correctness. Do all of that, and you are ready to ask the question. Until you can do that it's pointless trying to write real code.

Comment: Do you want to learn or not? If you don't want advice, I can certainly keep it to myself. You have for sure not solved your problems. Just swept them under the carpet. You have a lot to learn. We could help you do that.

Comment: Out of curiosity though, why is goto so obsolete? In my opinion is seems convenient.

Comment: Answer posted! The code in question does have its share of problems but I thought I should stick to the question at hand. One thing at a time. I would not recommend the use of 'goto'. It may be convenient but it creates code that can be hard to follow (jumps around :).

Comment: @karmasponge, thanks for clearing that up and a big thank you for resolving my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments: Who owns the memory for the 'neet_key'? My guess would be that the 'Message::Info' shows a valid value because whatever memory structure its from is still in memory but when you return its no longer in memory. Therefore the returned value prints rubbish.

This is a common issue for the C++ language. I would highly recommend that you avoid using raw pointers where possible (especially when returning from functions/methods). For strings you could obviously use 'std::string'.